# Laravel page speed - skip route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using [Laravel Page Speed](https://github.com/renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed).
This library create many problems with some styles in my admin pages and i want to skip that.

```
//config/laravel-page-speed.php

//You can use * as wildcard.
'skip' => [
    '*.pdf', //Ignore all routes with final .pdf
    '*/downloads/*',//Ignore all routes that contain 'downloads'
    'assets/*', // Ignore all routes with the 'assets' prefix
];
```

But when i want skip my admin url, nothing changed

```
'skip' => [
    '*/admin/*',
];
```

Do you have any idea about this problem?

**Update:** I also run these command after any change

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong syntax there. It should be like this :

```
'skip' => [
    'admin\*'
];
```

Check this issue from Github :

https://github.com/renatomarinho/laravel-page-speed/issues/45